# How to calculate two columns subtraction in PigLatin?

Tags: apache-pig, calculated-columns, difference

I have a table with 15 columnns.

2 of this columns has date format, for example: 09/08/2003. One column data_1 is a start date, another data_2 end date.

I need to count a difference between this to columns and to check if this difference is more than 30 days.

The result must be a table with column that shows values that are more than 30 days difference and all the other 15 columns.
Script could be something simmilar to this:

```
table = LOAD '$INPUT' AS (data_1, data_2, a1, a2, ... a13);
ggdif = (data_2 - data_1);
C = FILTER table BY (ggdif > 30) AS differ;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE a1 .. a13;
STORE D INTO '$OUTPUT' USING PigStorage('\t');
```

I have some problems with this task:

1. How to count a difference between 2 columns values?
2. How to put date in the right format in pig?

Answer (score 0):

Just write a simple UDF that takes in the 2 columns as input.

Could be `exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {`

Cast the `input(0)` and `input(1)` to `Date` and perform the subtraction.

Return the integer result.

Rest of it would be simply `filter`

Just to begin with, you could simply write a class

```
public class DateDifference extends EvalFunc<Integer>{

public int exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
// Here you could take input.get(0).toString() and form a Date out of it.
// Same for input.get(1)
// you could either use Java Date or can use Joda Jars for date difference.
// return the date difference as integer.
}
}
```

Prepare a jar of this.

In the pig shell

```
grunt> REGISTER jarname.jar

grunt> diffRow = foreach table generate FLATTEN(yourpackagename.DateDifference($0,$1)), and all your other columns...
```

Rest is simple, I think you can fill up with the rest.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, but for me it sounds a bit complicated. Can you explain on dummy level, please?

Comment: No Thanks and Sorry... http://wiki.apache.org/pig/UDFManual this gives you a very good handle on the UDF concept of Pig. Please feel free to drop a note if you need more assistance.

Comment: Thank You! I will try to manage it. I guess it is not the simpliest way, maybe exists any less complicated way to do it?